# iOS / iPhone - Take Quick Shot or Burst Photos

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, ios-camera

I have a requirement to build an photos taking app that allows the users to set the following features:

1. Set a delay before the photo is taken (e.g. 10 seconds)
2. Set the number of pictures to be taken in a shoot (e.g. 10 photos)
3. Set the delay between the pictures taken (e.g. 500 milliseconds)

I have seen apps around that have this functionality but cant figure out where in the documentation to look for a solution.

I know that in iOS7 there is a Burst Mode for the actual camera, but I need to achieve this programatically as the user is likely to be the subject of the photo and wont be touching the device when the pictures are taken.

The solution can be targeted at iOS7 devices only.

Does anyone know I how may approach or achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check out the excellent tools available in AVFoundation.
There are APIs to capture still images from the camera feed and sample code on how to do it. It's much faster than the standard image picker frameworks.

Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) for more.

I've used it on a few projects so ask away if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll take a look this evening and come back if I need a little more guidance